# XSLT Speed Difference Sum(PATH) vs. $variable for call-template optimization

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a slow XSL template that I am looking for any chance to optimize:

```
<!-- Ending columns for budget : called with P_LEDGER_TYPE == 'budget' -->
<xsl:template name="budget-special-cols">
  <!-- large pool of financial data -->
  <xsl:param name="cat"/>

  <xsl:param name="periods"/>
  <xsl:param name="sign" select="1"/>

  <!-- large pool of data for year over year budget -->
  <xsl:param name="yoy_budget"/>

  <!-- subsections of $cat based off of period of each row -->
  <xsl:param name="last_period" select="$cat[PERIOD=$periods[last()]]"/>
  <xsl:param name="trend_avg"   select="$cat[not(PERIOD=$periods[last()]) and not(PERIOD=$periods[1])]"/>
  <xsl:param name="trend_avg_len" select="P_REPORT_LEN - 2"/>

         <td class="ta-r"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(
           $sign * (sum($trend_avg/BUDGET) div $trend_avg_len)
           , '###,##0.00')"
         /></td>

         <td class="ta-r"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(
           (sum($trend_avg/BUDGET) div $trend_avg_len) - sum($last_period/BUDGET)
           , '###,##0.00')"
         /></td>

         <td class="ta-r"><xsl:value-of select="
           if ((sum($trend_avg/BUDGET) div $trend_avg_len)=0) then (0) 
           else format-number(
             ($sign * ((sum($trend_avg/BUDGET) div $trend_avg_len) - sum($last_period/BUDGET)) div (sum($trend_avg/BUDGET) div $trend_avg_len))*100
             , '###,##0.0')"
         />%</td>

         <td class="ta-r"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(
             $sign * (sum($last_period/BUDGET) - sum($yoy_budget/BUDGET))
             , '###,##0.00')"
         /></td>

         <td class="ta-r"><xsl:value-of select="
           if (sum($yoy_budget/BUDGET)=0) then (0) 
           else format-number(
                ($sign * (sum($yoy_budget/BUDGET) - sum($last_period/BUDGET)) div sum($yoy_budget/BUDGET))*100
                , '###,##0.0')"
         />%</td>
</xsl:template>
```

`$cat` and `$yoy_budget` represent groups of xml that have many different accounts in them.

My question is: Since I am summing off of several large pools of data, would it be best to create variables for the multiple `sum()` calls like so:

```
  . . .
  <!-- summed in call-template -->
  <xsl:param name="yoy_budget"/>

  <!-- subsections of $cat for based off of period for each row -->
  <xsl:param name="last_period" select="sum($cat[PERIOD=$periods[last()]]/BUDGET)"/>
  <xsl:param name="trend_avg"   select="sum($cat[not(PERIOD=$periods[last()]) and not(PERIOD=$periods[1])]/BUDGET)"/>
  <xsl:param name="trend_avg_len" select="P_REPORT_LEN - 2"/>
  . . .
```

Or are there any other obvious optimization techniques that I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: For performance questions, we really need to know which XSLT processor is involved. Optimization capabilities vary a lot.

Comment: @MichaelKay This using the processor that Oracle uses for their ERP platform. I believe it'd be this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14033/adx04xsj.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions like `sum($trend_avg/BUDGET)` or `sum($last_period/BUDGET)` seem to be used several times so you could certainly try to store each of them in a variable to see whether that improves performance.

As for other possible optimizations, `$cat[PERIOD=$periods[last()]]` seems to be a lookup so perhaps indexing the elements you have in `$cat` with a key on `PERIOD` e.g. `<xsl:key name="cat-by-period" match="CATEGORY" use="PERIOD"/>` and then using `key('cat-by-period', $periods[last()])` instead of `$cat[PERIOD=$periods[last()]]` improves things. I have used the element name/match pattern `CATEGORY` as an example, you haven't show the input structure so I don't know the exact name nor whether a simple match on that name suffices.

Comment: Thanks I figured I could change those variables to reflect the summed value as opposed to the underlying element/node...

As for using `xsl:key()`, I'm not sure that we could use it in this specific context. However I have other xslt templates that could certainly use it. Thanks for the tip there.